# Sprint boot database polling or listen database updates

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, triggers, spring-kafka

I have 2 *Spring Boot* applications let's say named ***App1*** and ***App2***. There is a table in oracle DB with status column.  when **App1** runs a scheduler, it will update that status column to ON or OFF.

***App2***(*with multiple instances*) is a Kafka consumer app, whenever it consumes an event it needs the status value from oracle to do some operation. I don't want to call oracle db every-time whenever the app consume an event, With initial application load I thought of fetching status value from DB and keeping that value in application context(in-memory) so that I don't need to make db calls.

*But Now the problem is, while keeping the status value in-memory, How would ***App2*** know when status value gets updated in oracle table* (***App1 updated the table***). *It needs to change that value in application context as well.*

How can I achieve that, are there any oracle table change listeners in spring boot or polling the data from database would be a good approach ??.

Please any suggestion would be helpful.

***Note:*** : This table gets updated only 4-5 times a day.

Comment: How is the precision requirement? When the table is changed, do all instances of App2 need to change behavior instantly, or could it be, as you described, a polling behavior that will reload, let’s say, every minute?

Comment: I want all instances to be updated instantly,  if polling happens every minute then whatever consumer app consumed in last minute then those events would get old status isn't it?

Comment: does event consumption in App2 happening quite frequently & is it heavy load?

Comment: Yes...The consumption in App2 would be quite heavy. 
but the status column gets updated only 4-5 times in a day. 
If you have any other approach , please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have App1 send an event to a specific topic to let App2 know something has changed and update its internal state accordingly.

Note that each instance would have to be in its own consumer group so that all can listen to the same event - you can assign a random UUID as consumer group.

Also, this should be very fast but there are no guarantees you wouldn’t get a few records on an outdated state. Anyway, in distributed systems you should generally embrace eventual consistency rather than try to make it behave like a monolith.

If you can’t make App1 send an event, there are such tools as Debezium https://debezium.io/  which listens to the DB and send events to Kafka, but that might be an overkill.

Another way would be having a distributed cache such as Redis, having App1 update it, and App2 checking it every time, which should be more performant than going to the DB.

Comment: Thank you, 
This status value gets updated only 4-5 times, so is it good approach to use a new topic alltogether for this ?? 
We are using Oracle database for all the other things, so I am not sure about spinning a new redis instances just for this.

Comment: TBH I don’t think you should be sharing the DB between services anyway. If app1 changes its state, it’s more than fair to communicate it through a Kafka topic - and it’s also the cheaper resource among the alternatives.

Comment: You should probably have a thoughtful  log compaction policy though - since instances will get random consumer groups, they’ll always start from the beginning of the topic, so the fewer records there the better.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more easy than what you describe

> With initial application load I thought of fetching status value from
> DB and keeping that value in application context(in-memory) so that I
> don't need to make db calls.

Expose another endpoint in **App2** where when invoked it updates the value it uses for status column which was initial loaded when application started up. This endpoint should be invoked from the scheduler of **App1** that is the one that invokes the changes in DB.

So in a simple sense the **App1** says hey **App2** instances I have just done some changes in DB. Please update the status you use from database so that you are up to date for your exchanges.

Edit:
If you afford having such complex infrastructure you can take a look on [spring-cloud-bus](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-bus) to broadcast a change in multiple services.

Comment: let's say App1 will call an API exposed by App2 to update the status used in application context, the consumer application App2 will have multiple instances , and only one instance will get that api request right????,

other instances will have that same value in application context, how will they know that status has been changed.
please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @APK yes you are correct you need to inform all instances of App2 in the same sheduler of App1.

Comment: I agree, if App1 was to let App2 know, the proper way of doing so would be through an event, which might be what you’re looking for.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos how can I inform all instances from same scheduler of App1 ??? can you please explain more

Comment: @TomazFernandes What type of events?, is it kafka events or something else, can you please suggest.

Comment: @APK. check editted answer about one possibility.