# How to implement a oracle db listener in spring boot application

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, triggers, listener

I have a table in ***oracle database*** and a ***spring boot application***, I want my spring boot application to listen to any change(update/insert) that happens in the table and do some operations after that.

I have seen some stack-overflow answers that suggests to use [DBMS_ALERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_alert.htm#CHDDJCJG) or ***Oracle AQ / Oracle Streams***.

Please let me know if it is possible to do that, If yes How can I implement it in spring boot application.
Please suggest if there is any other way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose theoretically you could create a `check timer function` in your spring boot application that would effectively check if any rows have been added to a table. That would take care of new rows. However for items that are updated or deleted , you could implement a trigger on the table object  and have a secondary table which would keep track of those changes and again you could check those table on pre-determined time interval for any changes from springboot application. You could look into `spring-jdbc` for examples on how to do CRUD operations. If you have any specifics questions post them up and we will try to help you. GOOD LUCK!

Comment: I have used cosmos DB, in that we have change-feed-listener library in spring boot , so I though we might have something like that oracle as well,   Mainly, I am trying to solve this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058143/sprint-boot-database-polling-or-listen-database-updates ) so thought of checking if we have any listeners. There are some suggestions given but not sure which one would be better. Please suggest if there is any other approach.